# How to use disable WebLogic authentication. Authentication denied. SecurityInitializationException

Tags: authentication, weblogic

When I try to start my WebLogic I get an authentication exception:

I try to disable the authentication / set authentication to a default embedded mechanism.

Any hints how to do that?

Error

```
<Jun 3, 2016 6:19:42 PM UTC> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
<Jun 3, 2016 6:19:42 PM UTC> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool>
<Jun 3, 2016 6:19:42 PM UTC> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file /vendor/appsrv/log/aaa_bbb_12345_cluster1/bin/aaa_bbb_32974_msi0_chlt2506091a_server_%yyyy%_%MM%_%dd%_%hh%_%mm%.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.>
<Jun 3, 2016 6:19:44 PM UTC> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.>
<Jun 3, 2016 6:19:44 PM UTC> <Critical> <Security> <BEA-090402> <Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.>
<Jun 3, 2016 6:19:44 PM UTC> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:960)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1054)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:888)
        at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090303]Authentication Failed: User bootUser weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnDelegateException: [Security:090295]caught unexpected exception
        at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:251)
        at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:110)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.login(LoginModuleWrapper.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jun 3, 2016 6:19:44 PM UTC> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED>
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<domain xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml/1.0/xacml.xsd
                            http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/domain.xsd
                            http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd
                            http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls/1.0/wls.xsd
                            http://www.vendor.com/ns/wls10/security/providers http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd
                            http://www.bea.com/ns/wlp/90/security/wsrp
                            http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator/1.0/passwordvalidator.xsd"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain"
        xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security"
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls"
        xmlns:xacml="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!-- No dsMdsSuffix used for disaster recovery -->
    <name>aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</name>
    <domain-version>10.3.5.0</domain-version>
    <security-configuration>
    <realm>

<!--Back End Credentials Provider-->
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-authenticatorType">
        <sec:name>DefaultAuthenticator</sec:name>
      </sec:authentication-provider>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-identity-asserterType">
        <sec:name>DefaultIdentityAsserter</sec:name>
        <sec:active-type>AuthenticatedUser</sec:active-type>
      </sec:authentication-provider>

      <sec:role-mapper xmlns:xac="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml" xsi:type="xac:xacml-role-mapperType">
        <sec:name>XACMLRoleMapper</sec:name>
      </sec:role-mapper>

      <sec:authorizer xmlns:xac="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml" xsi:type="xac:xacml-authorizerType">
        <sec:name>XACMLAuthorizer</sec:name>
      </sec:authorizer>

      <sec:adjudicator xsi:type="wls:default-adjudicatorType">
        <sec:name>DefaultAdjudicator</sec:name>
      </sec:adjudicator>

      <sec:credential-mapper xsi:type="wls:default-credential-mapperType">
        <sec:name>DefaultCredentialMapper</sec:name>
      </sec:credential-mapper>

      <sec:cert-path-provider xsi:type="wls:web-logic-cert-path-providerType">
        <sec:name>WebLogicCertPathProvider</sec:name>
      </sec:cert-path-provider>

      <sec:cert-path-builder>WebLogicCertPathProvider</sec:cert-path-builder>

      <sec:deploy-role-ignored>false</sec:deploy-role-ignored>
      <sec:deploy-policy-ignored>true</sec:deploy-policy-ignored>
      <sec:deploy-credential-mapping-ignored>true</sec:deploy-credential-mapping-ignored>
      <sec:fully-delegate-authorization>true</sec:fully-delegate-authorization>
      <sec:security-dd-model>Advanced</sec:security-dd-model>
      <sec:name>myrealm</sec:name>
      <sec:delegate-m-bean-authorization>true</sec:delegate-m-bean-authorization>
    </realm>
    <default-realm>myrealm</default-realm>
    <anonymous-admin-lookup-enabled>true</anonymous-admin-lookup-enabled>
        <credential-encrypted>weblogic</credential-encrypted>
    <node-manager-username>weblogic</node-manager-username>
    <node-manager-password-encrypted>weblogic</node-manager-password-encrypted>
    <enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
    <connection-logger-enabled>false</connection-logger-enabled>
  </security-configuration>
  <jta>
    <forget-heuristics>false</forget-heuristics>
    <max-resource-requests-on-server>1000</max-resource-requests-on-server>
  </jta>
  <log>
    <file-name>/vendor/appsrv/log/aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1/bin/wl-domain_%yyyy%_%MM%_%dd%_%hh%_%mm%.log</file-name>
    <rotation-type>bySize</rotation-type>
    <number-of-files-limited>true</number-of-files-limited>
    <file-count>50</file-count>
    <file-min-size>2000</file-min-size>
    <rotate-log-on-startup>false</rotate-log-on-startup>
    <logger-severity>Notice</logger-severity>
    <stdout-severity>Notice</stdout-severity>
    <domain-log-broadcast-severity>Notice</domain-log-broadcast-severity>
    <redirect-stdout-to-server-log-enabled>false</redirect-stdout-to-server-log-enabled>
  </log>
  <server>
    <name>aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1_server</name>
    <log>
      <file-name>/vendor/appsrv/log/aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1/bin/weblogic_%yyyy%_%MM%_%dd%_%hh%_%mm%.log</file-name>
      <rotation-type>bySize</rotation-type>
      <number-of-files-limited>true</number-of-files-limited>
      <file-count>50</file-count>
      <file-min-size>2000</file-min-size>
      <rotate-log-on-startup>false</rotate-log-on-startup>
      <logger-severity>Notice</logger-severity>
      <stdout-severity>Notice</stdout-severity>
      <domain-log-broadcast-severity>Notice</domain-log-broadcast-severity>
      <redirect-stdout-to-server-log-enabled>false</redirect-stdout-to-server-log-enabled>
    </log>
    <listen-port-enabled>true</listen-port-enabled>
    <cluster xsi:nil="true"></cluster>
    <web-server>
      <web-server-log>
        <file-name>/vendor/appsrv/log/aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1/bin/access_%yyyy%_%MM%_%dd%_%hh%_%mm%.log</file-name>
        <rotation-type>bySize</rotation-type>
        <number-of-files-limited>true</number-of-files-limited>
        <file-count>50</file-count>
        <file-min-size>2000</file-min-size>
        <rotate-log-on-startup>false</rotate-log-on-startup>
      </web-server-log>
      <send-server-header-enabled>false</send-server-header-enabled>
    </web-server>
    <iiop-enabled>false</iiop-enabled>
    <listen-address>0.0.0.0</listen-address>
    <administration-port>33077</administration-port>
    <xml-registry>CS_XML_Registry</xml-registry>
    <staging-directory-name>./stage</staging-directory-name>
    <classpath-servlet-disabled>true</classpath-servlet-disabled>
    <graceful-shutdown-timeout>180</graceful-shutdown-timeout>
    <ignore-sessions-during-shutdown>true</ignore-sessions-during-shutdown>
  </server>

  <server>
    <name>aaa_bbb_32974_msi0_chlt2506091a_server</name>
    <log>
      <file-name>/vendor/appsrv/log/aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1/bin/aaa_bbb_32974_msi0_chlt2506091a_server_%yyyy%_%MM%_%dd%_%hh%_%mm%.log</file-name>
      <rotation-type>bySize</rotation-type>
      <number-of-files-limited>true</number-of-files-limited>
      <file-count>50</file-count>
      <file-min-size>2000</file-min-size>
      <rotate-log-on-startup>false</rotate-log-on-startup>
      <stdout-severity>Notice</stdout-severity>
      <domain-log-broadcast-severity>Notice</domain-log-broadcast-severity>
      <redirect-stdout-to-server-log-enabled>false</redirect-stdout-to-server-log-enabled>
    </log>
    <listen-port-enabled>true</listen-port-enabled>
    <cluster>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</cluster>
    <web-server>
      <web-server-log>
        <file-name>/vendor/appsrv/log/aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1/bin/aaa_bbb_32974_msi0_chlt2506091a_server_access_%yyyy%_%MM%_%dd%_%hh%_%mm%.log</file-name>
        <rotation-type>bySize</rotation-type>
        <number-of-files-limited>true</number-of-files-limited>
        <file-count>50</file-count>
        <file-min-size>2000</file-min-size>
        <rotate-log-on-startup>false</rotate-log-on-startup>
      </web-server-log>
      <post-timeout-secs>30</post-timeout-secs>
    </web-server>
    <iiop-enabled>false</iiop-enabled>
    <listen-address>0.0.0.0</listen-address>
    <administration-port>33077</administration-port>
    <jta-migratable-target>
      <user-preferred-server>aaa_bbb_32974_msi0_chlt2506091a_server</user-preferred-server>
      <constrained-candidate-server>
      aaa_bbb_32974_msi0_chlt2506091a_server      </constrained-candidate-server>
      <cluster>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</cluster>
      <migration-policy>failure-recovery</migration-policy>
    </jta-migratable-target>
    <staging-directory-name>./stage</staging-directory-name>
    <classpath-servlet-disabled>true</classpath-servlet-disabled>
    <graceful-shutdown-timeout>180</graceful-shutdown-timeout>
    <ignore-sessions-during-shutdown>true</ignore-sessions-during-shutdown>
    <default-file-store>
      <directory>/vendor/share/tlog/aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</directory>
      <synchronous-write-policy>Direct-Write</synchronous-write-policy>
    </default-file-store>
  </server>

  <cluster>
    <name>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</name>
    <cluster-address>dummy.vendorintra.net</cluster-address>
    <multicast-address>239.194.64.67</multicast-address>
    <multicast-port>32974</multicast-port>
    <multicast-ttl>8</multicast-ttl>
    <cluster-messaging-mode>multicast</cluster-messaging-mode>
    <replication-channel>ReplicationChannel</replication-channel>
<!-- Special Engineering SE Start Timers -->
        <data-source-for-job-scheduler>XADataSource</data-source-for-job-scheduler>
    <job-scheduler-table-name>WEBLOGIC_TIMERS</job-scheduler-table-name>
<!-- Special Engineering SE End Timers -->
    <persist-sessions-on-shutdown>false</persist-sessions-on-shutdown>
    <data-source-for-automatic-migration>LeasingMDS</data-source-for-automatic-migration>
    <health-check-interval-millis>10001</health-check-interval-millis>
    <health-check-periods-until-fencing>31</health-check-periods-until-fencing>
    <fencing-grace-period-millis>30001</fencing-grace-period-millis>
    <number-of-servers-in-cluster-address>1</number-of-servers-in-cluster-address>
    <cluster-type>none</cluster-type>
    <auto-migration-table-name>ACTIVE_SINGLETON_SERVICES</auto-migration-table-name>
    <additional-auto-migration-attempts>3</additional-auto-migration-attempts>
    <millis-to-sleep-between-auto-migration-attempts>180000</millis-to-sleep-between-auto-migration-attempts>
    <migration-basis>database</migration-basis>
    <secure-replication-enabled>true</secure-replication-enabled>
  </cluster>
  <production-mode-enabled>false</production-mode-enabled>
  <embedded-ldap>
    <name>weblogic</name>
    <credential-encrypted>weblogic</credential-encrypted>
  </embedded-ldap>
  <administration-port-enabled>true</administration-port-enabled>
  <administration-port>33077</administration-port>
  <configuration-version>10.3.5.0</configuration-version>
  <app-deployment>
    <name>TOV1_TOM_MCON</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>/vendor/appsrv/app/aaa_bbb/TOV1/TOM_MCON.ear</source-path>
 <!-- START SE Special Engineering Deployment order -->
        <!-- Deployment order set to 98 by SE for TOM_MCON ear -->
        <deployment-order>98</deployment-order>
<!-- END SE Special Engineering Deployment order -->

    <security-dd-model>Advanced</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
  </app-deployment>
  <app-deployment>
    <name>TOV1_TOVear</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>/vendor/appsrv/app/aaa_bbb/TOV1/TOVear.ear</source-path>
 <!-- START SE Special Engineering Deployment order -->
        <!-- Deployment order set to 99 by SE for TOVear ear -->
        <deployment-order>99</deployment-order>
<!-- END SE Special Engineering Deployment order -->

    <security-dd-model>Advanced</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
  </app-deployment>

  <!-- Start policies for Webservices  -->
  <library>
    <name>CSWSPolicySAML#2.3@3.1</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <source-path>/vendor/appsrv/bin/wl10.3c/wlfw/lib/WSS12SAMLTwoOrSAMLOneOrIdentityCertWSPolicy.jar</source-path>
    <deployment-order>1</deployment-order>
    <security-dd-model>Advanced</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
  </library>
  <library>
    <name>CSWSPolicyUNPT11#0.0@1.2</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <source-path>/vendor/appsrv/bin/wl10.3c/wlfw/lib/WSS12UNPTWSPolicy.jar</source-path>
    <deployment-order>1</deployment-order>
    <security-dd-model>Advanced</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
  </library>
  <library>
    <name>CSWSPolicySAML11#1.0@1.2</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <source-path>/vendor/appsrv/bin/wl10.3c/wlfw/lib/WSS12SAML1WSPolicy.jar</source-path>
    <deployment-order>1</deployment-order>
    <security-dd-model>Advanced</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
  </library>
  <library>
    <name>CSWSPolicySAML20#2.0@1.1</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <source-path>/vendor/appsrv/bin/wl10.3c/wlfw/lib/WSS12SAML2WSPolicy.jar</source-path>
    <deployment-order>1</deployment-order>
    <security-dd-model>Advanced</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
  </library>
  <library>
    <name>CSWSPolicySAMLOneOrIdentityCert#1.1@3.1</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <source-path>/vendor/appsrv/bin/wl10.3c/wlfw/lib/WSS12SAMLOneOrIdentityCertWSPolicy.jar</source-path>
    <deployment-order>1</deployment-order>
    <security-dd-model>Advanced</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
  </library>
  <library>
    <name>CSWSPolicySAMLSAMLTwoOrIdentityCert#2.0@3.1</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <source-path>/vendor/appsrv/bin/wl10.3c/wlfw/lib/WSS12SAMLTwoOrIdentityCertWSPolicy.jar</source-path>
    <deployment-order>1</deployment-order>
    <security-dd-model>Advanced</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
  </library>
  <library>
    <name>HTTPSWebServicesPolicies#0.0@1.0</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <source-path>/vendor/appsrv/bin/wl10.3c/wlfw/lib/HTTPsPolicies.jar</source-path>
    <deployment-order>1</deployment-order>
    <security-dd-model>Advanced</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
  </library>
  <!-- End policies for Webservices  -->

  <!-- Shared Libraries -->
  <!-- End Shared Libraries -->
  <!-- External Shared Libraries -->
  <!-- End External Shared Libraries -->
  <xml-registry>
    <name>CS_XML_Registry</name>
    <document-builder-factory>org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl</document-builder-factory>
    <sax-parser-factory>org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl</sax-parser-factory>
    <transformer-factory>com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl</transformer-factory>
  </xml-registry>
  <migratable-target>
     <name>aaa_bbb_32974_msi0_chlt2506091a_server (migratable)</name>
    <notes>This is a system generated default migratable target for a server. Do not delete manually.</notes>
    <user-preferred-server>aaa_bbb_32974_msi0_chlt2506091a_server</user-preferred-server>
    <cluster>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</cluster>
  </migratable-target>



  <web-app-container>
    <work-context-propagation-enabled>false</work-context-propagation-enabled>
  </web-app-container>
  <jmx>
    <management-ejb-enabled>false</management-ejb-enabled>
  </jmx>
   <startup-class>
    <name>i3 Startup Class</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <class-name>com.precise.javaperf.extensions.weblogic.JMXMetricsLoader103</class-name>
    <failure-is-fatal>false</failure-is-fatal>
    <load-before-app-deployments>true</load-before-app-deployments>
  </startup-class>
  <mail-session>
    <name>TOM Mail</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <jndi-name>com.vend.v.mail.session</jndi-name>
    <properties>mail.transport.protocol=smtp;mail.smtp.dsn.ret=HDRS;mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=300000;mail.smtp.host=jap-mailgw-syn.rowini.net;mail.smtp.port=39101;mail.smtp.from=production.ofip@vendor.com;mail.smtp.allow8bitmime=FALSE;mail.from=production.ofip@vendor.com;mail.smtp.timeout=300000;mail.smtp.ehlo=TRUE;mail.smtp.auth=FALSE;mail.smtp.dsn.notify=NEVER;mail.smtp.sendpartial=TRUE</properties>
  </mail-session>


  <jms-system-resource>
      <name>WMQ_JMS_MODULE</name>
      <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
      <descriptor-file-name>jms/wmq-jms.xml</descriptor-file-name>

  </jms-system-resource>


  <admin-server-name>aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1_server</admin-server-name>

<!-- jdbc datasources -->
<!-- standard datasources -->

<jdbc-system-resource>
<!-- NO _DR in the name tag of jdbc-system-resource -->
    <name>XADataSource_ds2</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/XADataSource_ds2-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
</jdbc-system-resource>

<jdbc-system-resource>
<!-- NO _DR in the name tag of jdbc-system-resource -->
    <name>LeasingMDS_ds2_lease</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/LeasingMDS_ds2_lease-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
</jdbc-system-resource>

<jdbc-system-resource>
<!-- NO _DR in the name tag of jdbc-system-resource -->
    <name>XADataSource_ds1</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/XADataSource_ds1-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
</jdbc-system-resource>

<jdbc-system-resource>
<!-- NO _DR in the name tag of jdbc-system-resource -->
    <name>LeasingMDS_ds1_lease</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/LeasingMDS_ds1_lease-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
</jdbc-system-resource>


  <!-- multi-datasources for Oracle RAC -->

<jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>XADataSource</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/XADataSource-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
</jdbc-system-resource>

<jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>LeasingMDS</name>
    <target>xcluster_it_aaa_bbb_32863_cluster1</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/LeasingMDS-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
</jdbc-system-resource>
  <!-- end jdbc datasources -->

  <webservice-security>
    <name>default_wss</name>
    <policy-selection-preference>SCP</policy-selection-preference>
  </webservice-security>
  <internal-apps-deploy-on-demand-enabled>true</internal-apps-deploy-on-demand-enabled>
<!-- Special Engineering SE OOM Fix -->
<server-migration-history-size>100</server-migration-history-size>
<service-migration-history-size>100</service-migration-history-size>
<!-- Special Engineering SE END OOM Fix -->
</domain>
```

Comment: Starting a weblogic server instance requires to be authenticated. Removing all authentication providers will not resolve your issue. You must provide correct credentials in the boot.properties file if you want your server to start.

Comment: Thnx Emmanuel! I found my `bootIdentityFile` which replaces `boot.properties` in my server. Do you know which credentials I have to use inside the `boot.property`?

Comment: the same as you set when creating the domain.